# Declaring VB6 DLL Functions with two Dimensional Array

Tags: vb6, declare

I have these arrays:

```
Dim sInp(10) As String
Dim dInp(90) As Double
Dim sOut(500, 10) As String
Dim dOut(500, 100) As Double
```

Now I have to declare the following function:

```
Integer MyFunction(sInp, dInp, dOut, sOut)
```

How do I do that?
So far I have this Code:

```
Declare Function MyFunction Lib "C:\Path\To\My\dll.dll" (ByRef sInp() As String, ByRef dInp() As Double, ByRef dOut() As Double, ByRef sOut() As String): Integer
```

How do I make the last two params to multidimensional arrays?

I already did register the library and the IDE can find the function but I can't use it so I thought I have to declare it like this.

This is all of the documentation I got from the company:

```
Integer MyFunction(sInp, dInp, dOut, sOut )

sInp[10] (string type)
dInp[90] (double type)
sOut[500, 10] (string type) (The String are initialized as “”)
dOut[500, 100] (double type)  (The value are initialized as -9999.99 )
```

Comment: If you registered the library, then no, you mustn't `declare` it. You never tell what library it is and why is it that you cannot use it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, when i tried to call this Procedure like this: Ret = MyFunction(sInp, dInp, dOut, sOut) it told me "wrong number of Params or not correct Property Assigning"

Comment: It's a long time since I used VB6, but try Ret = MyFunction(sinp(), dinp(), dOut(), sOut())

Comment: Where is `MyFunction`? What's its signature?

Comment: When passing an array to a DLL you pass the first element. EG  `Function(MyArray(0))` You are passing the address of the beginning of the array. Also try passing by value.

Comment: @Lundt The first advice is inapplicable to COM functions, the second is wrong.

Comment: But it isn't a COM function. The `declare` says it is using Windows API calling conventions, ie *StdCall*.

Comment: @Lundt "*I already did register the library and the IDE can find the function*"

Comment: @GSerg He did say that. But he also declared it to be a standard call by using `Declare`. COM calls don't need or can use `declares`. As `declares` are `stdcall` while COM calls are different. His C code has no COM code to go with it.

Comment: @Lundt "*I can't use it so I thought I have to declare it like this*". Which [was wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There is no C code in the question in the first place.

Comment: > I already did register the library. In that case you don't need the method prototype (Declare ...). And if it _is_ a COM DLL, use the Object Explorer (F2) and locate the function there. This may give you a clue on how to pass the parameters.

Comment: Either what @HelO'Ween said is correct, or the DLL was not in fact registered (even if the OP did try regsvr32 on it)

Comment: I got A success Message when Registering it on regsvr32. After that i found the DLL in the Object Explorer and i added it with that checkbox. The IDE found it but i can't see what i have to pass to this Function. Normaly if u Put a "," in the Brackets after the Functionname, you get small above a hint what the Params look like, i do not get it.

Comment: `The IDE found` - where did the IDE find it? In a module? In a class? `but i can't see what i have to pass to this Function` - if the IDE found it, then surely you can see what to pass right there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say you registered the DLL with "regsvr32" and got a success message then it is an ActiveX DLL (a COM object) and as such you need to instantiate it as you do with any object. First you need to click Project -> References, look for the name of your DLL in the list and click the checkmark beside it. Then you can declare instances from it:

```
Dim ObjDLL as New WhateverTheDLLClassIsCalled
```

Then it should expose the "MyFunction" method and you should see its parameters:

```
Call ObjDll.MyFunction()
```

The "Declare Function MyFunction Lib" syntax is for regular DLLs that do not need to be registered.